# Getting Nested Types from Higher in Hierarchy in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, types, nested, hierarchy

I have a few classes called `SortMethod` which inherit from an abstract class called `ASortMethod`. Each of these classes is nested in another class. Right now, I'm dealing with the `SortMethod` inside of a class called `CitationCollection`.

There's another class I'm dealing with called `CustomSortDictionary`. This has to handle the given `SortMethod` type, but it's unknown which `SortMethod` type will be given, so I store a variable `Type sortMethod` in `CustomSortDictionary`.

This means I unfortunately have to deal with lots of messy reflection. Within the given `Type sortMethod`, there are two main things I'm looking to access. The first I was able to access using the below code, but the second I'm having trouble getting to.

```
BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;

// Accessing the first
MethodInfo m = SortMethod.GetMethod("ConstructCustomSortMethods", bindingFlags);
m.Invoke(null, null);

// Accessing the second
IDCollection customSort = (IDCollection)SortMethod.GetNestedType("CustomSort", bindingFlags).GetField("Methods").GetValue(null);
```

I've tried a few different combinations of `BindingFlags` to try to get to the nested type in the second piece of code, but I can't access it. I think the issue is that `SortMethod.CustomSort.Methods` is declared within `ASortMethod`, which is one step up the hierarchical ladder from `CitationCollection.SortMethod`.

How would I properly access this second item using reflection?

See [this link](http://pastebin.com/5ShQqcFr) for the full code.

**UPDATE:**

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx) from Microsoft's website, which may explain my issue:

BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
Specifies that public and protected static members up the hierarchy should be returned. Private static members in inherited classes are not returned. Static members include fields, methods, events, and properties. **Nested types are not returned.**

Comment: Can you provide a debuggable example?

Comment: @thehennyy You mean a method? That would take a lot of classes to spell out, snippets or no.

Comment: I think you have these classes somewhere, so you could just strip everything out that is not needed and only the relevant parts remain.

Comment: @thehennyy Here's what I observed while debugging: 1) CitationCollection.SortMethod.CustomSort.Methods exists; 2) (IDCollection)SortMethod.GetNestedType("CustomSort", bindingFlags).GetField("Methods").GetValue(null) does not. Let me know if you need any other details or if you want the code in full.

Comment: @thehennyy Here it is. http://pastebin.com/5ShQqcFr

Answer (score 0):

Your sort method *type* looks like this right?

```
public enum SortType { Ascend, Descend, FlyingTriangle }
```

You may want to use an interface so that all methods implementing it are required to either accept or reject a requested sort.

**Example**

```
public interface ISortable
{
    public bool IsValidContext(object record, SortType type);
}

public class SortAlpha : ISortable
{
    public bool IsValidContext(object record, SortType type)
    {
        return type == SortType.Ascend ? true : false; // example
    }
}

public class SortBeta : ISortable
{

    public bool IsValidContext(object record, SortType type)
    {
        return type == SortType.Descend && record is HtmlDocument; // example
    }
}
```

You can have a method iterate trough the classes implementing the interface to find and return the right one.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. `SortMethod` does not look like that. See [this link](http://pastebin.com/5ShQqcFr) for larger snippets of the raw code. I'm also a bit confused as to what an interface would do to help. I used an abstract class for what I think is a similar reason.

Comment: Another thing to note is that `SortMethod` is not an `enum`. It's a sealed class that stores `ID` objects in a fashion similar to how an `enum` works, but more flexible in being able to accommodate methods, nested types, other objects, etc.

Comment: Yeah it looks like you are using the Abstract class for the same reason. Interface just requires each class implementing it to have certain members so that nesting is not required. It looks like you can shorten your code to just one `Sorter` class. Just add various methods to handle different sorting styles. Then using it will look like: `Sorter sorter = new Sorter(data);` then `YourType sorted = sorter.Sort(someEnumType);`.

Comment: I wish! It's unfortunately a little more complicated in terms of structure... I agree that we used it for the same reason, but I can't avoid nesting, because I'm going to need `SortMethod` classes in other classes aside from `CitationCollection`. Plus, I'm using `CustomSortDictionary` to store those methods so that they can be added programmatically without actually stopping the program and editing the source code, since that isn't practical. This makes it easier for the future. The `IDs` you see in the code from Pastebin are used for identifying the methods.

Comment: Then, the `IDCollection` `CitationCollection.SortMethod.CustomSort.Methods` is used to store names in relation to those `IDs`, though that may sound a little ridiculous. I only did that so that it would feel like I'm working with fields with names, as with `SortMethod.Bibliography` or its siblings.

Comment: Does your sort method have to be able to sort a mix of different types of objects? If they are the same `Type` you can put `Sort()` in various `Citation<T>` classes..

Comment: I'm not sorting anything with one particular method. I'm talking about a class called `SortMethod`. Also, the `Citation` class does not have a generic parameter. I'm confused as to what you're asking. It is `CustomSortDictionary` that needs to be able to handle different types of objects, including `Citations`, since `Comparisons` require a type parameter.

Comment: Take a look at the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: What about generics with two type parameters? The `SortMethod` type in `CustomSortDictionary<T>` is kind of like a second type parameter, so there is technically still only one change being made, especially given that `CustomSortDictionary<T>` never directly deals with its type parameter `T`, since that's only used to determined what kind of `Comparison<T>` is being stored.

Answer (score 0):

Since the type `CustomSort` is always nested in `ASortMethod` you could just get it directly:

```
((IDCollection)typeof(ASortMethod.CustomSort).GetField("Methods").GetValue(null)).Add(ref name);
```

When you can not for some reason you could walk up the base types until you reach `object` to find the enclosing type of `CustomSort`

```
((IDCollection)FindBase(SortMethod).GetNestedType("CustomSort", bindingFlags).GetField("Methods").GetValue(null)).Add(ref name);

static Type FindBase(Type t)
{
    if (t.BaseType != typeof (object))
        return FindBase(t.BaseType);

    return t;
}
```

Comment: Only issue with using `ASortMethod` is that each `SortMethod` type will have a different `CustomSort.Methods` object. Unless there's something I'm misunderstanding with inherited static fields from abstract classes... could you clarify my misunderstanding? Otherwise, looks good. The recursive climbing is clever.

Comment: @Jenguinie To be honest, im not absolutely sure in this case but since the field is static, there is always only one field.

Comment: Welp, I guess there's only one way to find out... I'm going to test it and see if changing the value of one changes the value of the other.

Comment: The two are one and the same, unfortunately.

Comment: This whole structure is faulty, then... I'm going to have to make it into an interface after all, most likely.